# Returning character differences of two strings

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am working with a dataset of around 400k rows of preprocessed strings.

```
[In]:
raw                                preprocessed

helpersstreet 46, second floor     helpersstreet 46

489 john doe route                 john doe route

at main street 49                  main street
```

All strings in column 'preprocessed' are either same size or smaller than column 'raw'. Is there a fast way to compare these strings and return all differences, getting them in a column:

```
[Out]:
raw                                preprocessed        difference

helpersstreet 46, second floor     helpersstreet 46    ,second floor

489 john doe route                 john doe route      489

at main street 49                  main street         at 49
```

I am not really sure how to do this, but I am also wondering whether this is the way to go. I have access to the functions that perform the preprocessing, so is it faster to modify them to return these values or is the a scalable way to create the differences later. I would prefer the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Seems like an iterative replacement is in order. You can do this best using a *list comprehension*:

```
df['difference'] = [i.replace(j, '') for i, j in zip(df.raw, df.preprocessed)]

df    
                              raw      preprocessed      difference
0  helpersstreet 46, second floor  helpersstreet 46  , second floor
1              489 john doe route    john doe route            489 
2               at main street 49       main street          at  49
```

Given the limitations of this problem (the difficulty involved with vectorizing the replacement operation), I'd say this is your fastest option.

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, `np.vectorize` a `lambda`,

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda i, j: i.replace(j, ''))
df['difference'] = f(df.raw, df.preprocessed)    

df    
                              raw      preprocessed      difference
0  helpersstreet 46, second floor  helpersstreet 46  , second floor
1              489 john doe route    john doe route            489 
2               at main street 49       main street          at  49
```

Note that this only hides the loop, it is just as fast/slow as *Option 1*, if not worse.

---

**Option 3**
Using `apply`, which I don't recommend:

```
df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.raw.replace(x.preprocessed, ''), 1) 

df
                              raw      preprocessed      difference
0  helpersstreet 46, second floor  helpersstreet 46  , second floor
1              489 john doe route    john doe route            489 
2               at main street 49       main street          at  49
```

This *also* hides the loop, but does at a cost of more overhead than *Option 2*.

---

**Timings**
On request of my friend, Mr. jezrael:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)  # setup
```

```
# Option 1
%timeit df['difference'] = [i.replace(j, '') for i, j in zip(df.raw, df.preprocessed)]
186 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Option 2
%timeit df['difference'] = f(df.raw, df.preprocessed)  
326 ms ± 14.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Option 3
%timeit df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.raw.replace(x.preprocessed, ''), 1) 
20.8 s ± 237 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can you add timings?

Comment: Thank you for your very swift response, the first one works perfectly, but I will look into the others as well. Could you explain what you mean with 'the difficulty of vectorizing the replacement operation'?

Comment: @BramZijlstra Some functions in numpy/pandas can be "vectorised", meaning the operations can be computed in parallel inside the CPU. In this case, this is not possible, so the only option is to iterate using a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was a little bit vague. I know what vectorizing code is, but I still have a hard time thinking in vectorizing code when the functions are non-trivial. Do you have a good source on understanding when a problem can be easily vectorized and when not?

Comment: @BramZijlstra My understanding of pandas and numpy comes from answering many questions on the topic, and reading other answers by experienced users. It comes with experience, I suppose :) A general rule of thumb is that string operations are difficult to vectorize. Some can be (replacement, extraction, and so on), but not all.